# How to Only Show on Screen Markers With Google Maps Android API Utility Library

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been working with the Google Maps API Utility Library and I was wondering if there was a method to only display the on screen markers and clusters because whenever a user zooms in the map starts to lag when hundreds of markers are suddenly unclustered.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time when you zoom in/out the map, it will rerender itself, so the map is already displays on screen markers and clusters. The reason of the lags, I think, that map rerenders too much markers and clustermanager trying to clusterize at the same time. After some time map will be cached and there will be less lags. It's my opinion.

Comment: Okay thanks :) I'll do some further testing but that makes sense